# Node Js wont connect over http but will over https?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a site which is using node js to do a couple of things but i need it to connect over http not https.

This works;

```
var socket = io.connect("https://secure.tp.uk.com:3000");
```

But, this doesn't;

```
var socket = io.connect("http://secure.tp.uk.com:3000");
```

I get the error

> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Here is my node server script;

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express'),
app = module.exports.app = express();


var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

var demoUsers = [];
var tpUsers = [];
var activeGls = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   // here are all my functions which i know work because it works fine over https!!
});
```

It original worked over http but i was testing a few things with https but i was having issues with https on ios devices so now i need to get it working with http!

Here is my config file for site. /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secure.tp.uk.com
    ServerAlias secure.tp.uk.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Seeing the hosting configuration would be helpful (nginx, apache?), the configuration of a domain could very well make a site no accessible over one protocol even if it work in another. Testing it locally without hosting config could highlight if it's something in that area or not too.

Comment: i have added my conf file for the site.

Answer (score 0):

If i load both URL's in the browser, the one over http doesn't work there either, there is even a "secure" in the URL, so maybe the URL doesn't support http? Because, as i already mentioned, when you load the http URL in the browser, it won't load, so that's the explanation for EMPTY_RESPONSE i guess.

Comment: but why doesn't it load over http?? the secure part is just my subdomain.

Comment: are you 100% sure that you enabled access over just http? try accessing the URL in your browser, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes it needs to work over http. tried that and i see what you mean.